# String loses last character when concatenated with empty string in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I have a raw string and I cast it to a varchar2 and then cast it back to raw, all the original info is still there. However, if I cast it to a varchar2 and then concatenate anything onto it (including an empty string) I lose the last character.
This is the code I'm using to replicate it:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  raw_string RAW(100);
  v_string VARCHAR2(100);
  raw_string2 RAW(100);

BEGIN
    raw_string := 'C5C6C7';
    v_string := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(raw_string);

    dbms_output.put_line('Raw string:     ' || utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_string) );
    v_string := v_string || '';
    dbms_output.put_line('New raw string: ' || utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_string) );
END; 
/
```

The only difference between lines 11 and 13 is that line 13 is run after v_string is concatenated with an empty string. But the output is this:

```
Raw string:     C5C6C7
New raw string: C5C6
```

The new raw string will be the same if I don't concatenate anything on it, but if I add anything to the string, even at the front of it, it will lose that last part. It only happens with certain characters. If I end the raw with '61' (lowercase 'a') nothing will be lost.

I'm using Oracle SQl Developer v.3.2.20.09

This has been confusing me for a while now and I'm not sure if I am missing something or if this is just a bug, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I ran your script in Toad - Oracle 11g, and do not get the same result. `Raw string:     C5C6C7
New raw string: C5C6C7
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're playing with `RAWs` and `VARCHARs`, it's mandatory that you provide us with the character set that you're using (database character set and client cs).

The reason is that every byte value is legal for a raw byte, from `0x00` to `0xFF`. Whereas most character sets have illegal values: byte values that correspond to no character.

When Oracle encounters such values, the consequences can be unpredictable. This is likely what happens here.

For instance in UTF-8, a [byte whose binary representation starts with '110...' is the first byte of a two-byte character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

And it's exactly your situation: a byte that starts with a `C` has a binary representation that starts with `1100` and can only be the first byte of a two-byte character. The second byte has to start with `10..` (8 to B). So if I had to guess I would predict that you're using UTF-8, which is well-known for having many illegal byte values.

We can observe that using illegal UTF-8 values leads to many problems:

```
SQL> select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('C5C6') i0 from dual;

I0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ÅÆ

SQL> select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('C5C6')||'' i1 from dual;

I1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Å

SQL> select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('C5C6')||''||'' i2 from dual;

I2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In fact with any character set it's generally a bad idea to cast a raw blindly into a varchar2. **You only want to cast to varchar2 when you know that these values are legal** (ie the raw is itself a cast from varchar2).

When you need to represent a raw with a varchar2, for display or sending through a text medium, it is safer to use either [`hextoraw`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions073.htm#i1023950) or an encoding (for example `base64` with [`UTL_ENCODE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_encode.htm#i996731)).